# How to reset the default (graphics::) behavior of the plot function after loading LogisticDx?

Tags: r, plot, logistic-regression

The `LogisticDx` package commandeers the `plot` function.

Prior to loading `LogisticDx` if you fit a logistic model (with `glm` and `family=binomial`) you can get diagnostic plots simply with the plot command. After loading the `LogisticDx` package, when you try to plot a `glm` object, you can only get the `LogisticDx` version.

**Note1:** `LogisticDX` does not have a `plot` method. It somehow changes the plot function entirely. Thus there is no such thing as `LogisticDx::plot`.

**Note2:** Even after unloading the `LogisticDx` package, the `plot` function behavior for `glm` objects is still changed.

**Note3:** Even calling `plot` directly from the `graphics` library results in the altered behavior.

**Note4:** I just noticed that the `plot.glm` variant of plot is now missing.

There seems to be no way to restore the original `plot` function!

For example:

```
example(glm)
plot(glm.D93, ask=FALSE) # works
library(LogisticDx)
plot(glm.D93)
## Error in plot.glm(glm.D93) : x$family$family == "binomial" is not TRUE
```

Comment: Easier said than done. There is no terminal output here that is useful. The behavior is what happens when you run the `plot` command. Showing these plots will add no information either. I think it's enough to say that `LogisticDx` changes the behavior of the defaul `plot` command, and I can't get it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `stats:::plot.lm()`. (Confusingly, `plot.lm()` handles `glm` plots as well, that's why you couldn't find a `stats:::plot.glm`.)

```
example(glm)
plot(glm.D93, ask=FALSE)
library(LogisticDx)
try(plot(glm.D93))
## Error in plot.glm(glm.D93) : x$family$family == "binomial" is not TRUE
stats:::plot.lm(glm.D93, ask=FALSE)  ## works
```

- `LogisticDx` *does* have a `plot.glm` method, it's just hidden: `LogisticDx:::plot.glm`
- you're correct that `detach("package:LogisticDx")` won't remove the method definition.  The best you can do if you don't want to restart R is `plot.glm <- stats:::plot.lm` to mask the version from `LogisticDx`.

Comment: That's great! I don't completely understand the difference here between `::` and `:::`. When I don't want to load a library, I usually use the `::` operator to access a function. Clearly, here, I need `:::`. However, [the docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ns-dblcolon.html) caution against using that: "Beware --  use ':::' at your own risk! (see "Details")!"

Comment: `:::` is needed if you want to access un-exported (private, hidden) functions from a package. The danger is that, unlike exported functions, there's no guarantee that private functions are suitable for general use, or that they won't change in surprising ways in the future. (You're pretty safe with `stats:::plot.lm` though, I'm sure it hasn't changed in at least a decade.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. The question has gotten two downvotes so far. Seems pretty subtle to me.

Comment: It's back up to +1 ... it's almost always better to provide an example, even if you don't think it's really necessary ...